# Can't access a variable from another class in Java?

Tags: java, variables, methods, arguments

I am trying to call on a variable numFriends I created in another class but when I try to do so, it says "numFriends cannot be resolved to a variable". The variable is incremented each time a new friend is added and I want to display that in my Test class. Here's my code:

**CLASS ONE**

```
public class Person {

    private String fullName;
    private char gender; 
    private int age;

    public static int numFriends = 0;

    public Person(String nm, char gen, int a) {
        fullName = nm;
        gender = gen;
        age = a; 
        numFriends++;
    }

    public void setName(String nm) {
        fullName = nm;
    }

    public void setAge(int a) {
        age = a;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setGender(char g) {
        gender = g;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (fullName + ", gender = " + gender + ", age = " + age );
    }

}
```

**CLASS TWO (executable)**

```
public class TestPerson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(numFriends + " people at first");

        Person p1 = new Person("Otto Mattik", 'M', 22);
        p1.setName("Otto Mattik");
        p1.setGender('M');
        p1.setAge(22);
        System.out.println("Person Full Name = " + p1);

        Person p2 = new Person("Anna Bollick", 'F', 19);
        p2.setName("Anna Bollick");
        p2.setGender('F');
        p2.setAge(19);
        System.out.println("Person Full Name = " + p2);


        Person p3 = new Person("Dick Tator", 'M', 33);
        p3.setName("Dick Tator");
        p3.setGender('M');
        p3.setAge(33);
        System.out.println("Person Full Name = " + p3);

        changeName(p2, "Anna Bollik-Mattik");

        Person[] people = {
                p1, p2, p3
        };

        agePersons(people, 5);

        System.out.println("\n" + numFriends + " people after 5 years");

        for (Person person : people)
            System.out.println("Person fullName: " + person);

    }

    public static void changeName(Person p, String name) {
        p.setName(name);
    }

    public static void agePersons(Person[] people, int years) {
        for (Person person : people)
            person.setAge(person.getAge() + years);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Person.numFriends`. Also, you may consider making `numFriends` private and adding a static getter/setter to your `Person` class for it.

Comment: In the future, try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are only 2 lines here that are relevant, but I had to use Ctrl+F to find them in your code.

Comment: I doubt that numFriends should be static as I'm betting each Person should have its own numFriends field and value. You need to 1) possibly re-think your program design, and 2) open any Java book as this question is very basic Java, something that is best learned by reading your text or tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to say `Person.numFriends`. This is because numFriends is a static member of the Person class, so you need to use the Person class to reference numFriends.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. New at this so I really appreciate all of you guys' help.